# cv2.VideoCapture(0) crashes blender

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to use this script but it appears that it doesn't work on my machine.

I'm running Blender Version 2.81a (2019-12-04), on MacOS 10.14.6 (Mojave).

I have started a blank project, with just a cube in the middle, and a script :

```
import bpy
import cv2
import numpy as np


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None
    _cap = None
    _img = None
    _size = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

#        if event.type == 'TIMER':
#            ret, frame = self._cap.read()
#            resized = cv2.resize(frame, self._size, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
#            rgb = np.flip(resized, axis=[0, 2])

#            rgba = np.ones((self._size[1], self._size[0], 4), dtype=np.float32)
#            rgba[:,:,:-1] = np.float32(rgb) / 255
#            self._img.pixels = rgba.flatten()

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.5, window=context.window)
#uncommenting next line crashes Blender
        #self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#        self._img = bpy.data.images['image']
#        self._size = tuple(self._img.size)

        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        self._cap.release()



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

Specifically : 
`self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` crashes blender.
It seems like it's a python <=> Blender issue where python is asking to use the camera without permissions, so the app quits - i think -.

I have successfully used other script without crashing blender, such as the Templates in the `Scripting` tab -> `Templates` -> `Python`.

Might be some noob issue too, as I'm not very versed in blender....

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Best,

P

Comment: running Blender from the terminal solves it, as the terminal has full permissions : Go to Applications -> Blender ( right click show package contents ) -> contents -> MacOS. Right click on Blender, and open it with Terminal or iTerm.

Comment: Could you write that as an answer?